# is it possible to assign base class's struct to dervied class's struct

Tags: c++, struct, instantiation

I have class A which has struct as member and another class B which inherit class A and class B's struct inherit class A's struct.

```
class A
{
public:
    struct st
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    struct st : A::st
    {
        int z;
    };
};
```

following code give me error: what is the way to do this thing

```
B::st* obj = NULL; 

obj = new A::st [10];
```

Comment: You can do the reverse, namely create a new B object and have it assigned to an A object (case where you'd only see the A-specific fields). When you assign an A object to a B object, the B object is invalid (unless you have overloaded the assignment operator to do something valid), since B-specific fields are unknown.

Comment: I mean what should the value of z be after such an assignment?

Comment: That's pretty much equivalent to `A::st a[10]; B::st* obj = a;`. Even if you reverse the conversion so it typechecks – `B::st b[10]; A::st* a = b;` – it will be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying is wrong since `B::st` is sub-type of `A::st`. Hence, a pointer to `A::st` cannot be automatically converted to a pointer of type `B::st`.

For the same reason, you can't use:

```
B* bPtr = new A;
```

You can do the other way around.

```
A::st* obj = NULL; 
obj = new B::st;  // Don't use the array new. That is going to be problematic.
```

Comment: If you want to use an array, use `B::st*` not `A::st*`.